# Opening link in javascript widget in new window

Tags: meteor

I get the following error with this code in the update function below and I don't understand why.
err: [RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded]

Does it have something to do with using Meteor.setTimeout()?

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
          Meteor.clearTimeout(league.nextPickTimeoutId);

          var pickTimeoutId = Meteor.setTimeout(function () {
            Meteor.call('pickPlayer', leagueId, findTopScoringPlayer(leagueId, nextTeam._id)._id);
          }, 30*1000);

          Leagues.update(leagueId, {
            $set: {
              nextPickTill: new Date().getTime() + (league.secondsPerPick * 1000),
              nextPickTimeoutId: pickTimeoutId
            }
          }, function (err) {
            if (err) console.log('err:', err);
          });
        }
```

Comment: `Maximum call stack size exceeded` means that within a function you cause a chain of events that leads to the same function being invoked, without any boundary condition. You say the code provided is an update function - does it mean that it's inside update callback?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that:
Meteor.setTimeout() returns a handle that can be used by Meteor.clearTimeout. [Source](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_settimeout)

The Meteor.clearTimeout() function confused me that I thought took an id as an argument.